# Not able to install jaxlib

Tags: python, numpy, installation, pip, jax

I am trying to install jaxlib on my windows 10 by the following command which I found on the documentation..

> pip install jaxlib

It shows the following error

```
Collecting jaxlib
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jaxlib (from versions: None)
No matching distribution found for jaxlib
```

Comment: [from PyPL](https://pypi.org/project/jaxlib/#files) can download some wheels, then `pip install <jaxlib_whl_PC_path` & `pip install jax`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Jaxlib is not supported on windows you can see it here..
https://github.com/google/jax/issues/438

Comment: Thanks I was trying to install it for past 1 hour.

Comment: Yeah the easiest way is to use WSL to run JAX on windows

Comment: Outdated answer.

Answer (score 12):

Thanks to [cloudhan](https://github.com/cloudhan)'s [jax-windows-builder](https://github.com/cloudhan/jax-windows-builder), it is now rather easy to install [JAX and `jaxlib`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) on windows. E.g.

```
pip install jax==0.3.13 https://whls.blob.core.windows.net/unstable/cuda111/jaxlib-0.3.7+cuda11.cudnn82-cp38-none-win_amd64.whl
```

That's all.

---

As explained [there](https://github.com/cloudhan/jax-windows-builder#unstable-builds), I had to [copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPT6u.jpg) the *jaxlib*'s link address of the [whl file](https://realpython.com/python-wheels/) I was interested in, i.e. the `https://whls.blob.core...` above).

But I also had to take care that JAX's version and Jaxlib's were compatible, which compatibility is easy to assess at [github.com/google/jax/releases](https://github.com/google/jax/releases): just pick the last two of each *(!)*<sup>*the version numbers! nothing to download from there.*</sup>

---

***tested*** *with the versions explicited above*. <sub>*I.e. python3.8-64* **&** *jax==0.3.13* **&** *jaxlib-0.3.7*</sub>

Comment: cloudhan is having wheels only for windows 64x, do you know if there are wheels for win-32x somewhere? (can't find)

Answer (score 7):

I went through the process the last two days myself so here is what i did:

1. download and install the latest version of microsoft visual studio (
   to get a c++ compiler and toolchain)
2. download and install python
3. create a virtual python environment with the packages pip, setuptools, six, wheel and numpy (i did it in the GUI of pycharm)
4. [download jax](https://github.com/google/jax)

5. open up a windows powershell as administrator, change to the jax directory and complete the following steps (commands are in quotes)

- install chocolatey (package manager for easy bazel installation)

> Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force;
> [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol =
> [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex
> ((New-Object
> System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))

- install bazel (for building jaxlib)

> choco install bazel

- install msys2 (linux utilities for bazel)

> choco install msys2

- permamently link the python environment in your powershell

> [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", $Env:Path +
> ";C:\path\to\venv", "Machine")

- still beeing in the jax folder in powershell actually build and compile jax

> ./build/build.py

- after installation execute the command you're ask to to install jaxlib, it's something like

> pip install c:\...\jax\dist\jaxlib-0.1.72-cp39-none-win_amd64.whl

- and finally install jax with it

> pip install -e .

This way it worked for me, since the documentation on the jax homepage utterly confused me.

Comment: Running `./build/build.py` just opens the file, so I activated my virtual environment and ran `py ./build/build.py` instead. When I do that I get the follow error: `ERROR: Analysis of target '//build:build_wheel' failed; build aborted: Configuration Error: --define PYTHON_BIN_PATH='C:/users/username/documents/virtual-environment-folder/Scripts/python.exe' is not executable. Is it the python binary?`. This path is valid, do you have any suggestions on how to get around this?

Comment: I got around this issue by typing py ./build/build.py, but I wasn't in a virtual environment at the time.

Answer (score -1):

JAX does not provide jaxlib builds for Windows at this moment of time.

[Issue 1](https://github.com/google/jax/issues/438), [issue 2](https://github.com/google/jax/pull/4843)

But you can build it yourself if you wish.There are some comments in the above issue that might help you.

Answer (score -4):

This worked for me:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -Command "& 'C:\users\<username>\Anaconda3\condabin\conda_hook.bat' ; conda activate <yourcondaEnvironment>"
```