# trying to install "tflite-model-maker" in jupyter but got conflict with optax and jaxlib error

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda, tflite

I did these steps to install `tflite-model-maker`:

```
conda create --name myenv
conda activate myenv
pip install tensorflow
pip install tflite-model-maker
```

keep facing this issue:

```
ERROR: Cannot install flax because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:

    optax 0.1.5 depends on jaxlib>=0.1.37
    optax 0.1.4 depends on jaxlib>=0.1.37
    optax 0.1.3 depends on jaxlib>=0.1.37
    optax 0.1.2 depends on jaxlib>=0.1.37
    optax 0.1.1 depends on jaxlib>=0.1.37
    optax 0.1.0 depends on jaxlib>=0.1.37
    optax 0.0.91 depends on jaxlib>=0.1.37
    optax 0.0.9 depends on jaxlib>=0.1.37
    optax 0.0.8 depends on jaxlib>=0.1.37
    optax 0.0.6 depends on jaxlib>=0.1.37
    optax 0.0.5 depends on jaxlib>=0.1.37
    optax 0.0.3 depends on jaxlib>=0.1.37
    optax 0.0.2 depends on jaxlib>=0.1.37
    optax 0.0.1 depends on jaxlib>=0.1.37
```

tried to remove these packages but can not be removed:

```
conda remove --force optax='>=0.0.1' jaxlib='>=0.1.37'
```

What should i do?

Comment: Because you are using Anaconda/Conda as your package manager, you should always start there. Try `conda install -c conda-forge jaxlib` in your terminal.  Or add the magic `%` symbol to the start of that and try in the notebook where you want to work and then restart your kernel. (Command based on [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/jaxlib).) If you insist on `pip`, see [here](https://github.com/ikostrikov/implicit_q_learning/issues/3#issue-1040360896) or [here](https://github.com/google-research/t5x/issues/436#issue-1207106912) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72499565/8508004).

Comment: thanks but didn't solve the issue :(

Comment: Then you have to provide more information in your original post. You haven't even detailed what type of machine you are working on? [This issue](https://github.com/saharmor/dalle-playground/issues/65) looks very similar to yours; however I cannot tell how related it is because of lack of information in your original post. There's quite a bit of information packed into [the installation documentation for jax](https://github.com/google/jax#installation), linked to from [jaxlib Anaconda page](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/jaxlib). How in line with the suggestions there are you?

Comment: sorry i didn't see your answer till now, you're right i didn't provide much information, but really appreciate your help, i reached out with my supervisor doctor on my graduation project back then and she found another solution for me. thanks for your help :)